# Joystick in Battlefield 3

Tags: pc, battlefield-3

I wanted to use joystick ([Saitek Cyborg-X](http://cyborggaming.com/prod/v5stick.htm)) in Battlefield 3, but it's not working at all. The game doesn't detect it at all.

Is there any way to get it working? Flying jets with mouse isn't fun.

Comment: There are some people who had success activating it by deinstalling Cyborg drivers and re-plugging it, so that only Windows drivers are installed. There is also an alleged solution where you unbind every single keyboard and mouse action for the flying vehicles (jet & heli).

Comment: actually uninstalling drivers and installing latest downloaded from Saitek did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

- Uninstall your current drivers (whatever version just to be sure)
- Install the latest drivers downloaded from Saitek.
- Start the game and it should detect it.

Answer (score 0):

Comment: Welcome to Gaming! Thank you for the link. Since sites comes and go, [please include the essential parts](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) the content here and provide the link for reference/further information. You can use the ["edit"](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/34138/edit) link to modify your post. Thanks!

Comment: I haven't fixed the answer, because two Youtube links are useless to people without flash. Please consider adding content to the answer itself.